# Unable to run react native app android emulator

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I am trying to run a react-native project in VS code which is been imported from another system
But I am getting the following error, as follows

```
error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
Error: Command failed: ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
env: sh\r: No such file or directory

at makeError (/Users/Siva/Desktop/RN/Innoppl-Liberate/Mobile/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/node_modules/execa/index.js:174:9)
at /Users/Siva/Desktop/RN/Innoppl-Liberate/Mobile/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/node_modules/execa/index.js:278:16
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
at async runOnAllDevices (/Users/Siva/Desktop/RN/Innoppl-Liberate/Mobile/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/build/commands/runAndroid/runOnAllDevices.js:106:5)
at async Command.handleAction (/Users/Siva/Desktop/RN/Innoppl-Liberate/Mobile/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/index.js:192:9)
```

info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.

When I run the react-native project created in my own device, it is running good and the app is launched in the emulator.

It seems the android environment setup is working good for projects created in my own device where as the imported files have error - how to fix this

Comment: open the project's ./android/ in android studio and try to build there. It will suggest fixes to your gradle plugin better then executing ```run android``` from CLI

Comment: Try executong these commands in android folder instead of `react-native run-android`. 1- `./gradlew assembleDebug` 2- `./gradlew installDebug`

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this command at project root :

```
chmod 755 android/gradlew
```

Comment: tried but no use